# select part of table column data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'photo' which contains 2000 entries. That table has a column called `photo_note` which contains data in the format below but with different magnification value.

```
Magnification 30x. The resolution varies depending on.....
```

I need to select the rest of the column data starting with 'The resolution' and append it in another field 'photo_note_2'

Any suggestion how to do this in mysql is most appreciated

Comment: is the `photo_note` column always the same ? do you always want to start from `The resolution` ?

Comment: do u want to use mysql with php?

Comment: photo_note is more or less the same for all records except for the madnification value. Thanks for the help

Comment: For those who only need a specific string inside the data (not the rest of the data), [this question may be more suitable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871373/select-all-unique-emails-inside-a-column-filled-with-data).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` lets you return part of a string. `INSTR` returns the position of a string in other string.

If you know that all the columns will have 'The resolution', then:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(photo_note, INSTR(photo_note, 'The resolution')) from table;
```

If you know that all will have a 'x. ' before the string you want to retrieve, then

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(photo_note, INSTR(photo_note, 'x. ') + 3) from table;
```

You can see all the string functions for mysql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).