# Select all unique emails inside a column filled with data

Tags: mysql, select, substring, distinct

I have a column's field filled with all kinds of data from a user request (one request per row).

I only need the email addresses from these users' requests, and they are all placed in this column according to the following format:

```
[...data...] Email: mysql@se.com Phone: [...remaining data...]
```

I have found this question:

[select part of table column data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551051/select-part-of-table-column-data-in-mysql)

Which provides a solution for part of the problem:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(message,INSTR(message,'Email: ')+7) FROM user_req_log
```

However, this will return all the unwanted remaining data.

What's the most efficient way to confine the results to the strings I need (email addresses) and, at the same time, ignore duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that [question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10551207/1326147), you may simply do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(message,
                       @ini_pos:=INSTR(message,'Email: ')+7,
                       INSTR(message,' Phone:')-@ini_pos)
FROM `user_req_log`
```

It may not be the most efficient way, but it's fairly similar:

- use the three parameters of [`SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring);
- get the positions before and after the email address through [`INSTR(str,substr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) or [`LOCATE(substr,str)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_position)/[`POSITION(substr IN str)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_position).
- assign a variable for the email's initial position (`@ini_pos`) and
  reuse it to subtract from the position where you know it ends;
- use `DISTINCT` to return each email only once.